# "Error generating password due to missing uuid" when doing git push using SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to push my code to another developer's project, but I received the following error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master

Pushing to http://gitlab.ikij.cn:8888/gzt/maids.git
2018-04-05 15:45:44.003 git-credential-sourcetree[13297:1545908] Error
generating password due to missing uuid. Please report this to Atlassian.
2018-04-05 15:45:44.004 git-credential-sourcetree[13297I1459l0l] Something went
wrong. one or more parameters required to renew token is nil.
2018-04-05 15:45:46.234 git-credential-sourcetree[13297:1545908] Error
generating password due to missing uuid. Please report this to Atlassian.
2018-04-05 15:45:46.234 git-credential-sourcetree[13297:1545908] Password
encryption failed - key to to encrypt password is unavailable (nil)
remote: HTTP Basic Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http//gitLab.ikiji.cn:8888/gzt/maids.git/'

Completed with errors, see above
```

Comment: hi! welcome to SO. I guess English is not your main language (main either), but please try and add more information about your problem (try and make your question readable and easy to understand).

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)'s a document with some guidelines. good luck!

Comment: *`mnemonicprefix=fatse` is my spelling mistake

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with SourceTree v2.7.

Try to update SourceTree to a newer version (v2.7.2 for me).

SourceTree -> Preferences -> Check Now -> Install and Relaunch.